# Find total points for survey responses with associated point values

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have the results of some survey in Excel.
Each row represents the answers of one person in text from some predefined answers (e.g "often" "always" "not so much").
I want, at the end of the row, to add points according to the answers. For example, for each "always" answer, I want to add 4 points associated with that person. For answer "often," -2 points. etc.

I tried `COUNTIF`, but it just adds 1 point if the answer matches.

How can I add up the points for each person?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With data in **A1** through **H1**, in **I1** enter:

```
=COUNTIF(A1:H1,"often")*2+COUNTIF(A1:H1,"always")*4+COUNTIF(A1:H1,"not so much")*1
```

[image]

Comment: A more simple option that I used was to use the "find and replace" and I replaced the text with points and then I did the sum.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

[image]

The total is the multiplication of `COUNTIFS` and `Points`
Then you define the `Points` of each answer